# jQuery SlideToggle left space after minimized

Tags: jquery

I am working on jquery slidetoggle and i have a problem like
in the second row to last row there seems some error like after minimize still the sapce(height of that div) is there eventhough that div minimized.
Can anybody have an idea to clear that space please help me.

code is like

```
<div id="divRow1" style="width: 750px;">
            <div id="divEmployeeInfo" class="cmIndParent">
                <b class="RoundedBlue"><b class="RoundedOne"></b><b class="RoundedTwo"></b></b>
                <div id="divEmployeeInfoHeader" class="cmIndHeader" onclick="SlideToggle('divEmployeeInfoContent', 'PanelEmployeeState1');">
                    <label style="padding-left:1em; text-align:left">
                        Employee Information
                    </label >
                    <img style="float: right; padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 10px;" src="Images/expand.gif"
                        alt="Show details" />
                </div>
                <div id="divEmployeeInfoContent" class="cmIndContent hide-ui">
                    <br />
                    <uc1:ucEmployeeInfo ID="ucEmployeeInfo1" runat="server"></uc1:ucEmployeeInfo>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divJobInfo" class="cmIndParent">
                <b class="RoundedBlue"><b class="RoundedOne"></b><b class="RoundedTwo"></b></b>
                <div id="divJobInfoHeader" onclick="SlideToggle('divJobInfoContent', 'PanelEmployeeState2');"
                    class="cmIndHeader">
                    <label style="padding-left:1em; text-align:left" >
                        Job Information
                    </label>
                    <img style="float: right; padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 10px;" src="Images/expand.gif"
                        alt="Show details" />
                </div>
                <div id="divJobInfoContent" class="cmIndContent hide-ui">
                    <br />
                    <uc1:ucJobInfo ID="ucJobInfo1" runat="server"></uc1:ucJobInfo>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divEmployer" class="cmIndParent">
                <b class="RoundedBlue"><b class="RoundedOne"></b><b class="RoundedTwo"></b></b>
                <div id="divEmployerHeader" onclick="SlideToggle('divEmployerContent', 'PanelEmployeeState3');"
                    class="cmIndHeader">
                    <label class="cmLabelIndHeader">
                        Employer Information</label>
                    <img style="float: right; padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 10px;" src="Images/expand.gif"
                        alt="Show details" />
                </div>
                <div id="divEmployerContent" class="cmIndContent hide-ui">
                    <br />
                    <uc1:ucCompanyInfo ID="ucEmployer"    runat="server"></uc1:ucCompanyInfo>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="testRow" style="width:750px;padding-top: 1px">
            <div id="divTestCase" style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px; float: left; width: 740px;">
                <b class="RoundedBlue"><b class="RoundedOne"></b><b class="RoundedTwo"></b></b>
                <div id="divTestHeader" onclick="SlideToggle('divTestContent', 'TestPanelEmployeeState9');" class="cmIndHeader">
                    <label class="cmLabelIndHeader">
                        Test Information</label>
                    <img style="float: right; padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 10px;" src="Images/expand.gif"
                        alt="Show details" />
                </div>
                <div id="divTestContent" class="cmIndContent hide-ui">
                Hello
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

First row contains 3 columns of div working perfectly and the second row contains just one row.
I am using asp.net c# with jquery

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How high exactly is the space?  How high is the div before you hide? It might have something to do with the 5px margin you have set around the div divTestCase, that is a container for the div you are trying to hide.